# JavaScript - Can I show the content of a file in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tfs, content-type

In my server (TFS) I can access a file and get his content by a GET request,
The problem is that the **Content-Type** of the response is **application/octet-stream;**

And when I'm trying to load this file in an iFrame I get the **download windows popup to save this file**,

Is there a way to put the file content in this case in the iFrame? or some other way to get this file content in Javascript (XMLHttpRequest having some problems with application/octet-stream;)?

Comment: change the Content-Type header. Beyond that not enough detail provided

Comment: When I change it to lets say "json" , I get the file details, when it was created... when its text the response is content type is octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to change the content-type of the response of get request in TFS. By default is  application/octet-stream.

Comment: Not sure then how I should get the content of an attachment.. I'm trying to read an attachment from a build task. I got the link but when I tried to get the content I get 401.2 error. any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean you want to read the content from the build task to build summary page?  Here has a sample code that allows user to render custom data results uploaded from a particular task in build for your reference: [Build Results Enhancer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples#build-results-enhancer)

Comment: Well I used this example, but it's missing the important part. How to read the data from the link. If you can look at line #32 in this file  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/build-results-enhancer/src/enhancer/tab.ts

I got the url of the attachment that I uploaded but can't read it.
when I use $Get or ajax get I get a 401.2 error

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of the file you access. When you get "application/octet-stream" response, you may access some binary files or the file extension cannot be recognized. In this condition, you will get the response below which will suggest the agent to download the file:

```
content-type: application/octet-stream;
content-disposition: attachment
```

See [HTTP Standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) for details:

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet-
>   stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent
>   should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response
>   as...' dialog.

If you are accessing some general file types, you will get different response. For example:

```
a.txt -> content-type →text/plain;
a.ps -> content-type →application/json;
1.png -> content-type →image/png;
```